# PreloadedState not reflecting correctly after multiple combineReducers

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-reducers

The state of my application is as follows:

```
body: { data: [], style: {}}}, block:{}
```

I have 2 separate reducers for data and style and no reducer for body.
Am combining reducers in the following way:

```
const body = combineReducers({data, styles});
export default combineReducers({
    body,
    block
}) as Reducer<StoreState>;
```

Am passing the preloaded state as `body: {data: [{'data1': 'dataValue1'}], style: {key: value}}`
The issue is the preloaded state is not reflecting correctly for body. If I give data and styles directly in combineReducers the preloaded data is reflected correctly. Am unable to understand what am I missing. What is the correct way to achieve this behavior?

Comment: ['data1': 'dataValue1'] is it a valid syntax, i think you are trying to create a object

Comment: yes correct, edited the question. Basically am trying to reflect the preloaded state when I have the above hierarchy. However, its not able to apply it when I try it via the above way.

Comment: are you getting the initial state

Comment: yes, I get the initial state and all actions henceforth update the state correctly.

Comment: is it fixed or still the issue is there

Comment: the issue is still there. Preloaded state is not updated when I combine reducers in the above way

Comment: after combining how is the object

Comment: body: { data: [], style: {}}}, block:{} this is the final object

Comment: can you create a minimum reproducable code in codesandbox it will be helpful